# Optimization of a Java Method

Tags: java, arrays, optimization

Arthur and Alena are playing a game with an array containing some integers. Arthur can take any integer and remove it from the array and he has to add half of that number (rounded up) back to the array.
Alena allots Arthur a fixed number of moves and challenges him to minimize the sum of the final array.
As an example of how moves work, start with the array nums = [10, 20, 7] and perform k = 4 moves.

Pick any element to perform a move on, for example the 7. Perform the division: 7/2 = 3.5, and round up to 4. Replace the 7 with the new value 4. At this point, the array is nums = [10, 20, 4].  All 4 moves are performed as follows:

```
Pick    Pick/2    Rounded        Result
---------------------------------------------
Initial array                    [10, 20, 7]
----------------------------------------------
7         3.5        4           [ 10, 20, 4]
10        5          5           [5, 20, 4]
20        10         10          [5, 10, 4]
10        5          5           [5, 5, 4]
```

The sum of the final array is 5 + 5 + 4 = 14, and that sum is minimal.

Function Description

Complete the function minSum in the editor below. The function must return an integer denoting the minimum sum
of the array after k steps.

minSum has the following parameters:

```
nums[nums[0],...nums[n-1]]:  an array of integers

k:  an integer
```

Constraints

```
1 ≤ n ≤ 105
1 ≤ numi ≤ 104 (where 0 ≤ i < n)
1 ≤ k ≤ 107
```

Input Format For Custom Testing
Sample Case 0
Sample Input For Custom Testing

```
1
2
1
```

Sample Output

```
1
```

Explanation

The array has only one integer number, which is 2 and the number of steps to take on the array is one.
After the first step, the number 2 gets reduced to the number 1 and so, the minimum sum of the array after one step is 1.

This is yesterday's pair coding interview with one company:
What I thought:

1. Make this list as an arraylist
2. Convert into an array, too
3. Sort this array
4. Take the last element of this array and divided by 2 then assign back
5. Iterate the moves and sum up the array

I tried and ran the test cases and systems show some are not passed due to time out.

The results:

```
TestCase #0: Success
Output:
1

Expected Output:
1

TestCase #1: Success
Output:
4

Expected Output:
4

TestCase #2: Success
TestCase #3: Success
TestCase #4: Success
TestCase #5: Success
TestCase #6: Terminated due to timeout
TestCase #7: Terminated due to timeout
TestCase #8: Terminated due to timeout
TestCase #9: Terminated due to timeout
TestCase #10: Terminated due to timeout
TestCase #11: Terminated due to timeout
```

```
/*
 * Complete the 'minSum' function below.
 *
 * The function is expected to return an INTEGER.
 * The function accepts following parameters:
 *  1. INTEGER_ARRAY num
 *  2. INTEGER k
 */

public static int minSum(List<Integer> num, int k)
{
    // Write your code here
    // first of all: will have an arraylist for num
    // do the sanity check
    if(num==null || k<1)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(num);
    int[] convertedArray = new int[arrayList.size()];
    // convertedArray = arrayList.toArray();
    for(int i = 0; i<convertedArray.length; i++)
    {
        convertedArray[i] = arrayList.get(i);
    }

    // after the array implementation: sort the array
    Arrays.sort(convertedArray);  // this will get the sorted array
    int length = convertedArray.length;

    // for K times of movements
    for(int j=1 ; j<=k; j++)
    {
        int halfOfOrigianalNumber = (int)Math.round((double)convertedArray[length-1]/2);
        convertedArray[length-1] = halfOfOrigianalNumber;
        Arrays.sort(convertedArray);
    }

    //to sum up :
    int sumUp = 0;  //to sum up
    for (int i=0; i<convertedArray.length;i++)
    {
        sumUp+=convertedArray[i];
    }
    return sumUp;
}
```

My code can work but not all the test cases. Is there any optimization or fix I need to do on this method?

Thank you.

Comment: if performance is the issue, it might help to avoid real number operations. Thus, prefer, halfOfOrigianalNumber = (convertedArray[length-1]%2==0) ? convertedArray[length-1]/2 :1 + convertedArray[length-1]/2;

Comment: Also, it feels like all those sorts which are O(n log n) could be replaced with finding where the maximum element is in the array, which is O(n) and working on it.

Comment: use heap, the complexity is `klog(n)`

Comment: Quickest "divide rounding up" I know is (n + k-1) / k, works branchless with integer math only, and can optimize to bit shifts if k is a power of 2.

Answer (score 0):

You should utilize the standard library functions where possible. They offer a `PriorityQueue` class which maintain good (logarithmic add and removeHead operations) complexity operations. Which gives me the following implementation:

```
static int playGame(int turns, List<Integer> numbers) {
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(numbers.size(), (left, right) ->
            right - left
    );

    pq.addAll(numbers);

    for (int i = 0; i < turns; i++) {
        int next = pq.remove();
        pq.add((next + 1) / 2);
    }

    return pq.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for the help and comments.

Comment: I got the feedback from the interview saying that:  " he was just using a brute force approach and lacks design exp, rudimentary / generic responses on questions like challenges faced / optimizations.  "  It sounds bad but I am still appreciated that I can get the feedback. However, just within 20 to 30 minutes in a pair coding interview, how to perform without thinking of brute force approaches? this is what I am thinking how to improve.....  Thank you all for the ideas and comments.

Comment: The feedback was pretty good IMHO. You did a very brute-force approach to finding the minimum - realistically, it can only be either the number you just halved, or the one following it. Re-sorting the array each cycle was a massive waste. You used very basic tools, too - arrays are a foundation, but usually not a solution. See what higher-level constructs like `PriorityQueue` exist, and learn their strengths and weaknesses. That will get you further.